# How to get value from variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have bash script in which I am passing number of arguments and want to get argument at index specified

```
#! /bin/bash

index=$1
echo "argument at index $1 is" $[$index]

./temp.sh 3 1 2 5 6
argument at index 3 is 3

but I want output like
argument at index 3 is 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**indirect variable referencing**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver2.html#EX78):

```
#! /bin/bash

index="$1"
echo "argument at index: $index is ${!index}"
```

**OUTPUT:** (with your command line)

```
argument at index: 3 is 2
```